.net maui list view of a list with items of different subclass
I have a three classes defines:
    abstract public class PlanPosition
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public Plan? Plan { get; set; } = null;
        public int Pos { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressPos:PlanPosition
    {
        public Address Address { get; set; } 
        public LocomotionType LocomotionType { get; set; }
    }

    public class DayPos:PlanPosition
    {
        public int Day {  get; set; }
    }

I have a list of PlanPositions where the items are of AddressPos or DayPos.
Using a ListView with DataTemplate selector, i get a lot of bindings error. Here is an extract of the xaml code
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <util:DateOnlyToDateTimeConverter x:Key="DateConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AddressPosTemplate"
                      x:DataType="data:AddressPos">
            <ViewCell>
                <Border HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        WidthRequest="300"
                        Padding="5"
                        Margin="20"
                        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10">

                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="5">
                            <HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="HorizontalStackLayout" Binding="{Binding Pos}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
...
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="12"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </Border>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DayPosTemplate"
                      x:DataType="data:DayPos">
            <ViewCell>
                <Border HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        WidthRequest="100"
                        BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                        Padding="5"
                        Margin="10"
                        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           Spacing="5">
                        <Image Source="menu_burger.png" HeightRequest="20" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Day,StringFormat='Tag {0:D}'}" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <ImageButton x:Name="delButton" Source="trash.png" 
                                     HeightRequest="20" 
                                     IsVisible="False" 
                                     Padding="0"
                                     Margin="0"
                                     BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="delButton" Property="ImageButton.IsVisible" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="delButton" Property="ImageButton.IsVisible" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="150"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>

        <util:PlanPosDataTemplateSelector x:Key="PosSelector"
                                          AddressPos="{StaticResource AddressPosTemplate}"
                                          DayPos="{StaticResource DayPosTemplate}"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

The Source of the ListView is a List<PlanPosition>
The DataType of the different DataTemplates are AddressPos or DayPos.
I got errors like "Pos" Property is not found on ViewModel.
Schweregrad Anzahl  Datenkontext    Bindungspfad    Ziel    Zieltyp Beschreibung    Datei   Zeile   Projekt
Fehler  24  PlannerViewModel    Pos HorizontalStackLayout.Bound Object  'Pos' property not found on 'TripPlanner.Planner.PlannerViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.HorizontalStackLayout.Bound'  E:\NETProjects\Tripplanner\TripPlanner\Planner\PlannerPage.xaml 23  TripPlanner

Schweregrad Anzahl  Datenkontext    Bindungspfad    Ziel    Zieltyp Beschreibung    Datei   Zeile   Projekt
Fehler  14  PlannerViewModel    Day Label.Text  String  'Day' property not found on 'TripPlanner.Planner.PlannerViewModel', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'   E:\NETProjects\Tripplanner\TripPlanner\Planner\PlannerPage.xaml 52  TripPlanner


Is it not possible to display a listview with items of different classes?
I have no idea how to handle. I can create a display class that holds all attributues of all subclasses and display the approbrate property. But is not very objet oriented.

Could you please share the relevant code for the ViewModel?  How do you bind the ListView ItemSource?

I cannot reproduce this issue right now.  Please also include in the question what .NET version and platform do you use. For mvvm pattern, you may also refer to Data binding and MVVM
